# How to rotate the arrays within O(logN) time

Tags: arrays

When I studied the algorithm course in class, the professor came up with the question that how to rotate the n length arrays. For example, for the arrays {1,2,3,4,5,6}, n=6. Let k=3, after rotating the arrays, it will change to {4,5,6,1,2,3}. I could only get the algorithm O(n) time that using the % operation. But my professor told me that there exists a O(logN) algorithm. So I wonder how it achieves it and prove of it.

Comment: Moving `N` values in `log N` time seems impossible.

Comment: So it is the best to solve it in O(N) time?